# How do I set my relative path in a user controll that is shared

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, user-controls, relative-path

I have the following solution structure.

> - cabinet (folder)
>
>   - cabinet.aspx
> - images (folder)
> - script (folder)
>
>   - folder1
>
>     - menu.js
> - userControl (folder)
>
>   - menu.ascx
> - default.aspx

Inside of userControl I have `menu.ascx` (UserControl).

Inside of `menu.ascx` I am referencing several .js files.  For example:

```
<script src="./script/folder1/menu.js"></script>
```

When I view the `default.aspx` that calls `menu.ascx` it works fine.

However, when I'm in the cabinet folder looking at cabinet.aspx (`cabinet\cabinet.aspx`) that also calls `menu.ascx`

```
<%@ Register Src="../userControl/menu.ascx" TagName="menu" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
```

The menu code is in the source but the `menu.js` file is a **404**

```
http://localhost/cabinet/script/menu-files/menu.js
```

It looks like it needs to go directory further out.  I would of expected it to go to:

```
 http://localhost/script/menu/menu.js
```

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was the Visual Studio Web Instance that was being fired off and the fact that there were headers that needed to be set on IIS to allow the code to work.

So essentially I installed IIS 7.5 and created a site and now I just attach to the process to do my debugging for this.

Once I got IIS setup correctly the paths that were in code worked.

Answer (score 0):

One of two approaches:

1. Anchor the script reference to the site root with an absolute reference via "/script/folder1/menu.js" (note how it starts with a forward slash). For example, `<script src="/script/folder1/menu.js"></script>`. This says to look at the root of the site and carry on from there.
2. Have the script tag runat="server" and root it to the application root via "~/script/folder1/menu.js" (note the "~/" start). For example `<script runat="server" src="~/script/folder1/menu.js"></script>`. This determines the site root server-side and generates the correct path accordingly.

In all cases except for when your development environment doesn't allow it (I'm showing my age there going back to WinXP for development) or you are configuring an app that will live in a virtual application sub-directory in your site, go with the first option.

Comment: Hmmm...  I tried both of those and the 1st one didn't load the .js files and the 2nd one I got errors in my usercontrol at the declaration level: <%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="menu.ascx.vb" Inherits="UC_menu" %>

Comment: If the first one didn't work then you're not providing enough information. If you access the script file directly, what's the URL for it? I.e. http://localhost/script/folder1/menu.js?

Comment: And as to the second, what's the exception message?